# Bottle framework resource utilization

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I got a Python service running using Bottle framework. I've been noticing the request processing times constantly increasing over time while eating up the cpu. Are there any utilities to observe or debug the python processes running and how the resources are being used?

Thanks!

Comment: What engine are you using under Bottle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have osx or linux, check out: https://pypi.org/project/PSI/

If you need something for windows, use: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil